# Vue Material. Disable button effect (md-button)?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

any kind of documentation to disable the effect from the md-button?
Vue material

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of md-button with disabled attribute.  The button becomes disabled if loading or if the form is invalid using vuelidate validation library.

```
<md-button @click.prevent="signup" class="md-accent md-raised" :disabled="loading || $v.$invalid">Sign up</md-button>
```

Comment: Travis S, would you be willing to look at another Vue Material question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952741/how-to-set-up-flexible-grid-in-vue-material