# How to set up flexible grid in Vue Material

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flexbox, material-design, vue-material

I am attempting to build an interface that uses Vue-Material to render user-inputted cards in a grid. the cards render properly. However, I want my grid to flex, justify, and stagger the different-sized cards in a way that removes gaps, as seen below:

[image]

The following code corresponds with the above grid:

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="md-layout">
      <div
        v-for="post in posts.slice().reverse()" :key="post.id"
        class="md-layout-item md-size-20 md-xsmall-size-100"
      >
        <md-card>
          <md-card-content v-if="post.downloadUrl">
            <md-card-media>
              <img :src="post.downloadUrl" style="width: 100%"/>
            </md-card-media><br>
            <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
            <p>{{ post.timestamp | moment }}</p>
          </md-card-content>

          <md-card-content v-else>
            <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
            <p>{{ post.timestamp | moment }}</p>
          </md-card-content>
          <md-card-actions>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button md-info">
              <md-icon>favorite</md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button md-info">
              <md-icon>share</md-icon>
            </md-button>
          </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

How can I configure this Vue-Material layout to arrange the cards in a way that removes those gaps? Thanks!

[image]

Example #3

[image]

Comment: this seems like a css problem, try using min-height on your box div, I believe it is md-layout-item

Comment: that sort of works. I added ```.md-layout-item {
  height: 250px
}```but it still won't solve the issue of a small card positioned directly below a large card. See the new image I added above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `vue-masonry` plugin.

```
npm i vue-masonry
```

See it [working](https://qyr0i.csb.app/).
 Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-clarke-qyr0i).

Comment: Thanks, haha I actually figured that out right before you posted this. See my answer below. I really appreciate it though!

Comment: It's not the same plugin, though. The one I suggested has intro and resize animations. But I guess you know best what you want/need. Cheers! Normally I'd delete my answer, but since it's not exactly the same as yours, others with a similar problem might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **grid** layout:

```js
Vue.use(VueMaterial.default)

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(10px, auto);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui" name="viewport">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-material/dist/theme/default.css">

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <md-card>
        <md-card-media>
          <img src="https://vuematerial.io/assets/examples/card-image-1.jpg" alt="People">
        </md-card-media>
        <md-card-header>
          <div class="md-title">Card without hover effect</div>
        </md-card-header>

        <md-card-content>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio itaque ea, nostrum odio. Dolores, sed accusantium quasi non.
        </md-card-content>

        <md-card-actions>
          <md-button>Action</md-button>
          <md-button>Action</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
      </md-card>

      <md-card md-with-hover>
        <md-ripple>
          <md-card-header>
            <div class="md-title">Card with hover effect</div>
            <div class="md-subhead">It also have a ripple</div>
          </md-card-header>

          <md-card-content>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio itaque ea, nostrum odio. Dolores, sed accusantium quasi non.
          </md-card-content>

          <md-card-actions>
            <md-button>Action</md-button>
            <md-button>Action</md-button>
          </md-card-actions>
        </md-ripple>
      </md-card>
      <md-card>
        <md-card-header>
          <div class="md-title">Card without hover effect</div>
        </md-card-header>

        <md-card-content>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio itaque ea, nostrum odio. Dolores, sed accusantium quasi non.
        </md-card-content>

        <md-card-actions>
          <md-button>Action</md-button>
          <md-button>Action</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
      </md-card>

      <md-card md-with-hover>
        <md-ripple>
          <md-card-header>
            <div class="md-title">Card with hover effect</div>
            <div class="md-subhead">It also have a ripple</div>
          </md-card-header>

          <md-card-content>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio itaque ea, nostrum odio. Dolores, sed accusantium quasi non.
          </md-card-content>

          <md-card-actions>
            <md-button>Action</md-button>
            <md-button>Action</md-button>
          </md-card-actions>
        </md-ripple>
      </md-card>
      <md-card>
        <md-card-header>
          <div class="md-title">Card without hover effect</div>
        </md-card-header>

        <md-card-content>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio itaque ea, nostrum odio. Dolores, sed accusantium quasi non.
        </md-card-content>

        <md-card-actions>
          <md-button>Action</md-button>
          <md-button>Action</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
      </md-card>

      <md-card md-with-hover>
        <md-ripple>
          <md-card-header>
            <div class="md-title">Card with hover effect</div>
            <div class="md-subhead">It also have a ripple</div>
          </md-card-header>

          <md-card-content>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio itaque ea, nostrum odio. Dolores, sed accusantium quasi non.
          </md-card-content>

          <md-card-actions>
            <md-button>Action</md-button>
            <md-button>Action</md-button>
          </md-card-actions>
        </md-ripple>
      </md-card>
      <md-card>
        <md-card-header>
          <div class="md-title">Card without hover effect</div>
        </md-card-header>

        <md-card-content>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio itaque ea, nostrum odio. Dolores, sed accusantium quasi non.
        </md-card-content>

        <md-card-actions>
          <md-button>Action</md-button>
          <md-button>Action</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
      </md-card>

      <md-card md-with-hover>
        <md-ripple>
          <md-card-header>
            <div class="md-title">Card with hover effect</div>
            <div class="md-subhead">It also have a ripple</div>
          </md-card-header>

          <md-card-content>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio itaque ea, nostrum odio. Dolores, sed accusantium quasi non.
          </md-card-content>

          <md-card-actions>
            <md-button>Action</md-button>
            <md-button>Action</md-button>
          </md-card-actions>
        </md-ripple>
      </md-card>
    </div>
    &copy Image linked from https://vuematerial.io/
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-material"></script>
```

More on **CSS grid**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

## ANOTHER SOLUTION

You could use

Andy Barefoot's solution: https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb (Codepen: https://codepen.io/andybarefoot/pen/QMeZda),

or any from here: https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/

Unfortunately I cannot add it as a snippet - the content is too long, so my answer would be over 30,000  characters.

Comment: Sort of, but I am using a v-for directive to loop through all of the cards then return them to the screen, in order of post number (see the images). The cards will represent different sizes. I want the cards to render in a manner similar to Image example #3 above, in a nice,staggered grid, with no gaps. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Oh, **Pinterest** (masonry) style?

Comment: Yes! Masonry style. How can this be achieved in the above template?

Comment: Meaning, how can masonry be applied to each looped card item? when a long card sits under a short card (see above images), how can they be configured to confirm to a masonry layout without creating gaps in the rows and columns?

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 I added another solution - that works for sure; you need to customize it though (classes, JS objects, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who responded today. However, what I needed was a plugin like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-masonry-css

All I needed to do was embed the v-for loop container and the cards inside the following:

```
<masonry
  :cols="3"
  :gutter="30"
  >
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">Item: {{index + 1}}</div>
</masonry>
```

THIS is what I was trying to achieve:

[image]